# Add Close-Icon to embeded Youtube-Video

Tags: jquery, html, css

the question is saying it:

**How am I able to add an Icon to and embeded Yotube-Video-Window?**

Comment: You can click outside the player or press the escape key to close it. Which most people will try before looking for a close button.

Comment: yeah, that was my thought too, but my client wants something like that ... :(

Comment: If it's a must I would suggest to add the button through js rather than rely on youtube here

Comment: Please don't link to your site. Your question needs to contain everything required to answer it **in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with **jquery** , see an example below :

```js
$(function(){
    
      $(".closeBtn").click(function(){
        $($(this).data("target")).fadeOut(500);
      });
    
});
```

```css
.closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="v1">
 <div class="closeBtn" data-target="#v1"><img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/delete--delete-icon-32231.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
        <iframe width="932" height="510" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v5dU-dG9epY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```